# When I right click nothing happens

Tags: interface, 3d-view

Is there a way to fix this? In Youtube tutorials, when they right click they get some options such as mesh, etc but I don't get anything please help.

Comment: You need to add more to your question. When you right click on what? In the 3D view, by default, right click is for selection.

Comment: Right click is used for selection of objects in most views. Could you please add a link to the tutorial? You get the menu to add a mesh by pressing [Shift]+[A] while your mouse is inside the 3D view window.

Comment: What appears to be contextual menus in the 3dview are actually shown in response to key presses not right clicking. Right clicking on most properties and buttons displayed outside the 3dview does give a contextual menu though.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is very obscure, but what I think you are looking for is the *Add* menu?
You can get to this menu by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. The resulting menu looks like this:

[image]

This menu is used to add objects to the scene, from lighting, to meshes, to curves, to armatures, to add-on generated objects.

Comment: that did not answer my question but does solve the problem...